# Indexing columns by name in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very large data frame and to avoid the hassle of finding the number of the column to select it, can I select with square brackets by name?

as in

```
test_vec <-sample.df[,'sample_column']
```

Comment: The answer is yes, but I assume it didn't work since you are here asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Please note the following codes:

```
mtcars[, "mpg"]  # This will result in a vector as output

[1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 32.4
[19] 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7 15.0 21.4
```

If you want to preserve the data structure (data frame) as the input, set the `drop` argument to `FALSE`:

```
mtcars[, "mpg", drop = FALSE]

                     mpg
Mazda RX4           21.0
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0
Datsun 710          22.8
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4
Hornet Sportabout   18.7
Valiant             18.1
Duster 360          14.3
Merc 240D           24.4
Merc 230            22.8
Merc 280            19.2
Merc 280C           17.8
Merc 450SE          16.4
Merc 450SL          17.3
Merc 450SLC         15.2
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4
Lincoln Continental 10.4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7
Fiat 128            32.4
Honda Civic         30.4
Toyota Corolla      33.9
Toyota Corona       21.5
Dodge Challenger    15.5
AMC Javelin         15.2
Camaro Z28          13.3
Pontiac Firebird    19.2
Fiat X1-9           27.3
Porsche 914-2       26.0
Lotus Europa        30.4
Ford Pantera L      15.8
Ferrari Dino        19.7
Maserati Bora       15.0
Volvo 142E          21.4
```

Or you can drop comma and just use name subsetting:

```
mtcars["mpg"]     # The data structure of the output is preserved

mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl", "am")]     # For subsetting multiple columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, precisely with the syntax you used. You can also select multiple columns with `c()`. Single brackets return a `data.frame`object, while double brackets will return a `vector`.
Alternatively, for subsetting big data frames, `dplyr::select` is a good friend

```
library(dplyr)
df.subset <- select(sample.df,c(all_column_names))
```

If your columns of interest have a *text_pattern*, (eg: all contain "foo") you could do:

```
df.subset <- select(sample.df, contains("foo"))
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? The syntax is correct, and the approach is simple?